# Principal $n$th root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

This is really two questions.

1. Is there a definition of the principal $n$th root of a complex number? I can't find it anywhere.
2. Presumably, the usual definition is $[r\exp(i\theta)]^{1/n} = r^{1/n}\exp(i\theta/n)$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, but I have yet to see this anywhere. Is this because it has bad properties? For instance, according to this definition is it true that for all complex $z$ it holds that $(z^{1/a})^b = (z^b)^{1/a}$?

Comment: "Principal nth root"...under what definition of the word "principal"?

Comment: @DonAntonio I dunno, but surely you have to choose a "principal" or "default" or "canonical" root before the quadratic formula makes sense, for example.

Comment: Another problem is that there are n nth roots of a complex number. I may no longer be a function, or even two, but simply a solution set to an equation.

Comment: Well, unless there are specific requirements in some problem @user18921 , you *do not* get to choose anything: most probably you have to list down **all** the roots.

Comment: Maybe just pick the one that is the maximum in some way (absolute value would not work unfortunately.)

Comment: That last answer that was just deleted. Maybe define it as when k=0.

Comment: @PyRulez That's exactly how I defined it.

Comment: For 2) take $z = i, a=2, b=4$.

Comment: It is consistent with the real number definition of principal root?

Comment: @Stefan Good point, $[i^{1/2}]^4=-1$, but $[i^4]^{1/2}=1$

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, it's consistent. e.g. If $x > 0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is positive. Also, if $x > 0$, then $\sqrt{-x}=i\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Wikipedia says that it may be chosen in a variety of ways: ["A principal root of a complex number may be chosen in various ways."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Complex_roots)

Comment: I prefer to start with principal argument satisfying $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$.  Then the principal square-root is in the (closed) right half-plane, and is continuous in a neighborhood of the positive reals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There really is *not* a coherent notion of "principal" nth root of a complex number, because of the inherent and inescapable ambiguities.

For example, we *could* declare that the principal nth root of a positive real is the positive real root (this part is fine), but then the hitch comes in extending this definition to include all or nearly all complex numbers. For example, we could try to require *continuity*, but if we go around 0 clockwise, versus counter-clockwise, we'd obtain two different nth roots for number we've "analytically continued" to. A/the traditional "solution" (which is not a real solution) is to "slit" the complex plane along the negative real axis to "prevent" such comparisons. And some random choice about whether the negative real axis is lumped together with one side or the other.

But even avoiding that ambiguity leaves us with a root-taking function that substantially fails to be a group homomorphism, that is, fails to have the property that the nth root of a product is the product of the nth roots.

The expression in terms of radius and argument "solves" the problem by not really giving a well-defined function on complex numbers, but only well-defined on an infinite-fold (ramified) *covering* of the complex plane... basically *giving* oneself a logarithm from which to make nth roots. But logarithms cannot be defined as single-valued functions on the complex plane, either, for similar reasons. Partially defined in artificial ways, yes, but then losing the fundamental property that log of a product is sum of the logs.

Answer (score 3):

If $z=|z|e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{C}^*$, then there's exactly $n$ numbers $w_k,k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $w_k^n=z$:
$$w_k=\sqrt[n]{|z|}e^{i(2k\pi+\theta)/n},\quad k=0,\ldots,n-1.$$

The principle root is when $k=0$.

Comment: Which one is the principle root (there is a hint in the comments.)

Comment: Doesn't work unless you specify a deterministic method for selecting $\theta$. According to your definition the principal roots of $z_1=e^{i\pi/2}$ and $z_2=e^{i5\pi/2}$ are different. Yet $z_1=z_2$.

Comment: Ah, ok I assume that $\theta$ is the principal argument i.e. $0\leq \theta<2\pi$.

Comment: @user63181 Your definition doesn’t preserve the principle odd roots of negative real numbers.  For example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$, not $1+i\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Might I add, there is no universal definition of a principle nth root in the complex number system.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw, [According to Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=principal+3rd+root+of+-8), the principal 3rd root of $-8$ actually is $1+i\sqrt{3}$