# Why the alternate form of $\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i 2$ is $\sqrt[6]{-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, arithmetic

The alternate form of:
$$\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i 2$$
is 
$$\sqrt[6]{-1}$$
(I know that thanks to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sqrt(3))%2F2%2Bi%2F2).)

What are the arithmetic actions that gets us from the former to the latter?

Comment: Well you can simply raise $\sqrt{3}/2+i/2$ to the sixth power and find out that you get $-1$.

Comment: The two forms are not equivalent. $\sqrt[6]{-1}$ is an ambiguous presentation of 6 different complex numbers.

Comment: Related: ["Principal $n$th root of a complex number"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322481/409).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a terrible notation by Wolfram. There are six sixth roots of $-1$, so you cannot tell which one it is when you write $\sqrt[6]{-1}$.

The notation makes sense when we write $\sqrt{2}$, say, because we take the usual convention that it is the positive root. But such choice is meaningless for arbitrary roots.

The sixth roots of $-1$ are, from De Moivre's formula (and writing $-1=\cos\pi+i\sin \pi$), 
$$
\omega_k=\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi+2k\pi}{6}\right)+i\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi+2k\pi}{6}\right),\ \ k=0,\ldots,5.
$$
Your root is $\omega_0$ above. It is what we call a *primitive* root, in the sense that 6 is the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $\omega_0^r=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{3}/2+i/2=\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6)=e^{i\pi/6}"="(e^{i\pi})^{1/6}=(-1)^{1/6}.$$

The second equality is Euler's theorem. The third equals sign is in quotes is because technically there are $6$ values of $(e^{i\pi})^{1/6}$, and $e^{i\pi/6}$ happens to be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

We simply have that

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i 2\right)^6=(e^{i\pi/6})^6=e^{i\pi}=-1$$

and since $\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i 2$ is the principal root of $z^6+1=0$ for that reason it is designed as $\sqrt[6]{-1}$.

Refer also to:

- [Principal $n$th root of a complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322481/505767)

Comment: This demonstrates that $\sqrt{3}/2+i/2$ is *a* sixth-root of $-1$, but it doesn't explain why the value deserves the designation "$\sqrt[6]{-1}$".

Comment: That's the principal root! Ok I add something more on that.