How to find principal value of the cubic root?
I tried to find principal value for $\sqrt[3]{z}$ , I started from
$$ z=w^3 $$
So
$$ w_1=\sqrt[3]{r} \exp\left(\frac{Arg(z)}{3} i\right)$$
$$ w_2=\sqrt[3]{r} \exp\left(\frac{Arg(z)+2\pi}{3} i\right)$$
$$ w_3=\sqrt[3]{r} \exp\left(\frac{Arg(z)-2\pi}{3}i \right)$$
now which solution is a principal value?
I thought its $w_1$ which mean $Arg(\sqrt[3]{z})=\frac{Arg(z)}{3}$
but Wolfram-alpha says that $\sqrt[3]{-1-i}=\sqrt[6]{2}\exp\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}i \right)$ but $Arg(-1-i)=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$
So it must be as I think $Arg(\sqrt[3]{-1-i})=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ therefore $\sqrt[3]{-1-i}=\sqrt[6]{2}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}i \right)$
what is the wrong here ? is wolfram made wrong ?

What is your definition of a principal value ?

@FançoisGatine a principal value mean choose one of many possible values since the function must has one value for all domain
in roots function we have in square root to solutions and  the principal value has positive real part because of principal of $Arg(z)$ function
in cubic roots from $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we can get that principal value has positive real part
and Im searching for better condition that is true for choosing a value that remains true to the definition $arg(z)$ and square root

You can't make a continuous function $f$ over $\mathbb C$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb C(f(x)^3=x)$.

Wolfram-Alpha will report the one you liked if the input is rewritten as (-1-i)^(1/3) .

To follow up on the comment of @FançoisGatine, your response to that comment does not give a well-defined description of the principle value.

@LeeMosher ok can you help me in that ? there must be only one value for cubic root So how can I define it and how to find ?

Well, right there is the big problem. The thing to face when writing "There must be only one value for cubic roots" is a simple mathematical fact that you already know: the equation $z^3=a$ has three different complex valued solutions for any complex number $a \ne 0$. If you like, you can give a rule which selects one of those solution for each $a$. But just giving a name for a rule, like "principal value", is not sufficient if you don't also give the mathematical definition.

@LeeMosher choosing one of three solution is not randomly it must be follow what $Arg(a)$ and $\sqrt{a}$ defined So I used the name for that rule to show that is related for functions we used to calculate cubic root for a number>

Fair enough, except for one point. Your title question is How to find principal value of the cube root, and your post itself asks "Is Wolfram wrong?" Each of those questions presumes that a definition for the principal value of the cube root already exists and is already known.

Closely related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322481/principal-nth-root-of-a-complex-number

@LeeMosher So you mean there is no Agreed definition for a principal value of cubic root ? and I checked your link and found "There really is not a coherent notion of "principal" nth root of a complex number"

That's correct. The one described in the answer of @ZackFisher is a perfectly reasonable choice. One can make other choices. There is no particular mathematical reason to prefer one over the other, besides convention and/or agreement. And there are reasons not to insist on any one choice, as that answer in that link explains.

@LeeMosher So can be $\sqrt{1}=-1$ correct ? since there is no particular mathematical reason to choose $1$ or $-1$ .

Interestingly, for the square root function defined on $[0,\infty)$, the mathematical community has long ago rallied around a convention, namely that if $x \ge 0$ then $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$. But for the square root function defined on $\mathbb C$, yes, I can imagine a convention producing the output $\sqrt{1}=-1$. For instance, one might wish to invert function $w=z^2$ with domain restricted to the left half plane $\text{Re}(z) < 0$.

According to a comment on the similar question, the first non-real root as you traverse counter clockwise from the positive real axis is chosen by Mathematica.
